# SET is not working when re-assigning a variable in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

When I re-assign a variable it is not reflecting. Please find the below code

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 set sstep=1
 set kstep=2
 set estep=5

 IF %kstep% GTR %estep% (
 GOTO END
 )
 echo test
 set sstep=2
 echo !sstep!
 :END
```

But the output i am getting is as follows

```
test
!sstep!
```

And i want the output to be as

```
test
2
```

If I remove ! mark from the above code it is printing the following output

```
test
1
```

Comment: `echo %sstep%` will give you the desired output

Comment: @PM 77-1 
I didn't added that part, i tried with that also

     echo %sstep% 
but this code also gives me the same output i.e test and 1

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 enterprise

Comment: works for me.How the script is called? are there additional switches to cmd.exe ?

Comment: I doubt that this is the whole code. This snippet works for me as intended (I'm on Win7 Enterprise). I'm getting the same output as you do when I remove `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. A typo somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

#### Is extensions enabled/disabled for the user or system?

Look in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` for the `EnableExtensions` value. Set it to 1 to enable or 0 to disable.

#### Is the shortcut that starts cmd.exe disabling extensions?

You can try launching your batch file directly like below.

Enable command extensions

```
c:\>cmd.exe /E:ON mycommand.bat
```

Disable command extensions

```
c:\>cmd.exe /E:OFF mycommand.bat
```